# Custom sink for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, heapster

Is it possible to define a custom sink for Prometheus? Such a [feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/sink-configuration.md) is offered by Heapster, and I wonder if one can, for example, write collected time series data by Prometheus to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote write path allows for this, see https://www.robustperception.io/using-the-remote-write-path/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Is it possible to export the data as a json object, for example?

Comment: The remote read API is the only API offered for this, you can write an adapter that converts that output to JSON.